# Running OpenResty as a service on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nginx

I need to use Nginx with Lua and a sheaf of other extensions enabled so I have followed the instructions at https://openresty.org/ and compiled the OpenResty variant of Nginx.  That process went pretty smoothly and now I have nginx at `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/`.  The version reported when I execute `./nginx -v` is 1.9.3.2 - correct. I can get the server up and running by executing `./nginx`.

However, what I would like to be able to do is to have it run as a service at startup the way it usually works when you do a vanilla Nginx install via `apt-get install nginx`.  I would also like to be able to use commands such as `service nginx status|restart|stop|reload` etc.  I am an utter and complete newbie when it comes to this sort of thing.  I have tried to understand the contents of the `/etc/init.d/nginx` script on one of my other servers but modifying it to work with the present installation is not something I understand.  I am hoping that someone here will be able to help.

Comment: What nginx init script are you referring to, the one installed by `apt-get install nginx`?

Comment: @ThomasW.- yes that is what I meant by the nginx init script. In the mean time I have found [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frdmn/service-daemons/master/debian) which helps but it does not help me do `service nginx reload`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### And now, the Ubuntu answer.

You are using Ubuntu Linux. You already have either upstart or systemd (the former in this particular case). *Do not begin by writing System 5 `rc` scripts.*

So write an upstart job file.  Take one of the ones *already written* for nginx, in fact, and modify it for OpenResty.

[The Ubuntu version 15.10 nginx-common package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/nginx-common) comes with an upstart job file supplied, straight out of the box, as `/etc/init/nginx.conf`; although [the Ubuntu version 14.04 nginx-common package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nginx-common) is several versions behind and does not.  It's fairly easy to pull the file directly out of the Debian source repository ([`nginx.upstart`](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/nginx.git/tree/debian/nginx-common.nginx.upstart)).  There's also an `/etc/init/nginx.conf` job file on the nginx wiki.

Applying your OpenResty modifications yields this:

```
# /etc/init/openresty.conf

description "OpenResty nginx"

start on filesystem and static-network-up
stop on runlevel [016]

env DAEMON='/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf'

expect fork
respawn

pre-start script
    [ -x $DAEMON ] || { stop; exit 0; }
    $DAEMON -t || { stop; exit 0; }
end script

exec $DAEMON 

pre-stop exec $DAEMON -s quit
```

Use as an upstart job, in the usual manner, with `initctl start`, `initctl stop`, and so forth.

Of course, people have already done these modifications, long since.

### Further reading

- Oliver Frommel (2014). [`/etc/init/openresty.conf`](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2014/19/The-OpenResty-distribution-for-Nginx#article_l1). *The OpenResty distribution for Nginx*.  *ADMIN Magazine*  19.
- Edward Stone (2013-02-18).  [`nginx-upstart.conf`](https://github.com/eadmundo/openresty-pypi/blob/master/puppet/modules/openresty/templates/nginx-upstart.conf).  openresty-pypi.  GitHub.
- George Shammas (2015-08-11). [`/etc/init/nginx.conf`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/ubuntuupstart/).  nginx wiki.