# Ubuntu service started from /etc/init.d ends up with the wrong PID

Tags: 14.04, nginx, init.d

This question follows on from my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705484/running-openresty-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-14-04).  To recap

- I want to use OpenResty rather than vanilla Nginx on my Ubuntu 14.04 server.
- I have complied OpenResty following the instructions [here](https://openresty.org/).
- The compiled `nginx` ends up in `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin'
- I can now do `./nginx` from that folder to launch nginx.

The problem is that I need to have the ability to do stuff like `service nginx status|reload|start|stop` as I would normally do if I were using the vanilla version of Nginx installed via `apt-get install nginx|nginx-extras` etc.

My knowledge of such issues is quite basic. However, by dint of hacking the `/etc/init.d/nginx` script that is created by `apt-get install nginx` and modifying the ideas described [here](http://blog.frd.mn/how-to-set-up-proper-startstop-services-ubuntu-debian-mac-windows/) I have created my own `/etc/init.d/nginx` script which I reproduce below

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="nginx"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
APP="/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx"

if [ -r /etc/default/nginx ]; then
 . /etc/default/nginx
fi

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

PID=$(cat /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf | grep -Ev '^\s*#' | 
awk 'BEGIN { RS="[;{}]" } { if ($1 == "pid") print $2 }' | head -n1)
if [ -z "$PID" ]
then
   PID=/var/run/nginx.pid
fi

if [ -n "$ULIMIT" ]; then
 ulimit $ULIMIT
fi

start() {
 printf "Starting '$NAME'... "
 start-stop-daemon --start --background --make-pidfile --pidfile    
 /var/run/$NAME.pid --exec "$APP"
 printf "done\n"
}

killtree() {
 local _pid=$1
 local _sig=${2-TERM}
 for _child in $(ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid ${_pid}); do
    killtree ${_child} ${_sig}
 done
 kill -${_sig} ${_pid}
}

stop() {
 printf "Stopping '$NAME'... "
 [ -z `cat /var/run/$NAME.pid 2>/dev/null` ] || \
 while test -d /proc/$(cat /var/run/$NAME.pid); do
  killtree $(cat /var/run/$NAME.pid) 15
  sleep 0.5
 done 
 [ -z `cat /var/run/$NAME.pid 2>/dev/null` ] || rm /var/run/$NAME.pid
 printf "done\n"
}

case "$1" in
 start)
   start
   ;;
 stop)
  stop
  ;;
 restart)
  stop
  start
  ;;
reload)
  start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid 
  --name nginx
  ;;            
status)
 status_of_proc -p /var/run/nginx.pid "nginx" "nginx" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;

*)
 echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload|status}" >&2
 exit 1
 ;;
esac

exit 0
```

With this in place if I reboot my server and issue a `lsof -nP -i | grep LISTEN` I get the output

```
nginx     2247     root    6u  IPv4  14166      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     2248   nobody    6u  IPv4  14166      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

One of the things I do not understand here - why two users:root & nobody?  So if I visited by server from a browser and executed a PHP script it would be run as - *nobody*, *root*...?

I examined `/var/run/nginx.pid`.  The PID recorded there is **2146**, i.e. 1 **LESS** than what is reported above and when I run `netstat -anp | grep 80`.

I tried this last step several times over - multiple reboots - with always the same result.  Naturally, this meant that subsequent attempts to reload or stop Nginx via `service nginx reload` and `service nginx stop` failed: WRONG PID!

When I manually edited `/var/run/nginx.pid` to ensure that it has the **right** PID things work as expected.

I have to admit that I am working beyond my knowledge of how such matters work here.  I'd much appreciate any help fixing the issues I have run into here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting the answer here in the hope that it will save others the hours of frustration I have had to endure.  The easy issue to deal with here is the `nobody` user that I talk of above. This happens quite simply because the `nginx.conf` file created by openresty - see

`/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

does not bother specifying a user. Just edit the first line

`#user nobody` so it reads `user www-data www-data` and that particular issue is sorted.

The second issue is the `init.d` script.  I am afraid that the openresty documentation has to take the blame here.  They go to some lengths to explain how to get openresty & how to compile it.  A few words on how to daemonize it would not have gone amiss.

After hours of groping in the dark I thought of searching for **openresty init.d**.  The very first result that came up was [this one](https://gist.github.com/vdel26/8805927).  I am reproducing that script below

```
#!/bin/sh


PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="Nginx Daemon"
NAME=nginx
PREFIX=/usr/local/openresty/nginx
DAEMON=$PREFIX/sbin/$NAME
CONF=$PREFIX/conf/$NAME.conf
PID=$PREFIX/logs/$NAME.pid
SCRIPT=/etc/init.d/$NAME

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ ! -x "$DAEMON" ] || [ ! -f "$CONF" ]; then
 echo -e "\033[33m $DAEMON has no permission to run. \033[0m"
 echo -e "\033[33m Or $CONF doesn't exist. \033[0m"
 sleep 1
 exit 1
fi

do_start() {
 if [ -f $PID ]; then
    echo -e "\033[33m $PID already exists. \033[0m"
    echo -e "\033[33m $DESC is already running or crashed. \033[0m"
    echo -e "\033[32m $DESC Reopening $CONF ... \033[0m"
    $DAEMON -s reopen -c $CONF
    sleep 1
    echo -e "\033[36m $DESC reopened. \033[0m"
 else
    echo -e "\033[32m $DESC Starting $CONF ... \033[0m"
    $DAEMON -c $CONF
    sleep 1
    echo -e "\033[36m $DESC started. \033[0m"
 fi
}

do_stop() {
 if [ ! -f $PID ]; then
    echo -e "\033[33m $PID doesn't exist. \033[0m"
    echo -e "\033[33m $DESC isn't running. \033[0m"
 else
    echo -e "\033[32m $DESC Stopping $CONF ... \033[0m"
    $DAEMON -s stop -c $CONF
    sleep 1
    echo -e "\033[36m $DESC stopped. \033[0m"
 fi
}

do_reload() {
 if [ ! -f $PID ]; then
    echo -e "\033[33m $PID doesn't exist. \033[0m"
    echo -e "\033[33m $DESC isn't running. \033[0m"
    echo -e "\033[32m $DESC Starting $CONF ... \033[0m"
    $DAEMON -c $CONF
    sleep 1
    echo -e "\033[36m $DESC started. \033[0m"
 else
    echo -e "\033[32m $DESC Reloading $CONF ... \033[0m"
    $DAEMON -s reload -c $CONF
    sleep 1
    echo -e "\033[36m $DESC reloaded. \033[0m"
 fi
}

do_quit() {
 if [ ! -f $PID ]; then
    echo -e "\033[33m $PID doesn't exist. \033[0m"
    echo -e "\033[33m $DESC isn't running. \033[0m"
 else
     echo -e "\033[32m $DESC Quitting $CONF ... \033[0m"
     $DAEMON -s quit -c $CONF
     sleep 1
     echo -e "\033[36m $DESC quitted. \033[0m"
  fi
}

do_test() {
 echo -e "\033[32m $DESC Testing $CONF ... \033[0m"
 $DAEMON -t -c $CONF
}

do_info() {
 $DAEMON -V
}

case "$1" in
 start)
  do_start
  ;;
 stop)
  do_stop
  ;;
 reload)
  do_reload
  ;;
 restart)
  do_stop
  do_start
  ;;
status)
    status_of_proc -p $PID "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
 quit)
  do_quit
  ;;
 test)
  do_test
  ;;
 info)
  do_info
  ;;
 *)
  echo "Usage: $SCRIPT {start|stop|reload|restart|quit|test|info}"
  exit 2
  ;;
 esac

 exit 0
```

An omission in the original script which I have corrected - there was no `status` method.